# sinatra cant load javascript files after that I server in public folder(because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable )?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, sinatra

Im trying to load  javascript file but appears a MIME type error ; dont works I dont know how solve

How i could solve this

this is my html code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="/2"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var param = { salutation: 5+6, name: "Friend" };
        $.post("greeting", param, function(result) { 
          console.log("param",param);
          $("#greeting").html(result);
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Sinatra Ajax Demo using jQuery</h1>
    <div id="greeting">
      <p>Hello, World</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is my ruby sinatra  code

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'pp'

get '/' do
  erb :index
end



get '/2' do
  File.read(File.join('public', 'jquery-1.7.1.js'))

end


post '/greeting' do
  #puts "params"
  #pp params

  "<p>#{params[:salutation]}, #{params[:name]}</p>"
end
```

Please help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve with this

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'pp'

get '/' do
  erb :index
end



get '/2' do
  content_type 'text/javascript'
  File.read(File.join('public', 'jquery-1.7.1.js'))

end


post '/greeting' do
  #puts "params"
  #pp params

  "<p>#{params[:salutation]}, #{params[:name]}</p>"
end
```